# Выравнивание инпутов в форме

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая форма:
[image: форма]

Как выровнять, чтобы инпуты были строго друг под другом?

Правильно ли я сверстал структуру?

```html
<form className='form'>

  <div className="city">
    <label htmlFor="city">Ваш город</label>
    <select id="city" name="city">
      <option value="moscow">Москва</option>
      <option value="st-petersburg">Санкт-Петербург</option>
      <option value="novosibirsk">Новосибирск</option>
      <option value="ekaterinburg">Екатеринбург</option>
      <option value="kazan">Казань</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <hr className='line' />

  <div className="password">
    <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
    <div className="password_descr">
      Ваш новый пароль должен содержать не менее 5 символов.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="password">
    <label htmlFor="password">Пароль еще раз</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
    <div className="password_descr">
      Повторите пароль, пожалуйста, это обезопасит вас с нами на случай ошибки
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr className='line' />

  <div className="mail">
    <label htmlFor="email">Электронная почта</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
    <div className="mail_descr">
      Можно изменить адрес, указанный при регистрации.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="agree">
    <div className="agree_title">Я согласен</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="consent" name="consent" required />
    <label htmlFor="consent">принимать актуальную информацию на емейл</label>
  </div>

  <div className="btn">
    <button type="submit">Изменить</button>
    <div className="btn_descr">последние изменения 15 мая 2012 в 14:55:17</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: есть несколько способов: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520057/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-html-form) при помощи отступов или таблицы. есть более современные техники: флексбоксы и гриды. вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099601/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-input-%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5) пример с флексбоксом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как выровнять, чтобы инпуты были строго друг под другом?

Начать можно с самого очевидного - стилизовать лейблы нужных полей.

```css
.format {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<form className='form'>

  <div className="city">
    <label htmlFor="city" class='format'>Ваш город</label>
    <select id="city" name="city">
      <option value="moscow">Москва</option>
      <option value="st-petersburg">Санкт-Петербург</option>
      <option value="novosibirsk">Новосибирск</option>
      <option value="ekaterinburg">Екатеринбург</option>
      <option value="kazan">Казань</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <hr className='line' />

  <div className="password">
    <label htmlFor="password" class='format'>Пароль</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
    <div className="password_descr">
      Ваш новый пароль должен содержать не менее 5 символов.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="password">
    <label htmlFor="password" class='format'>Пароль еще раз</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
    <div className="password_descr">
      Повторите пароль, пожалуйста, это обезопасит вас с нами на случай ошибки
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr className='line' />

  <div className="mail">
    <label htmlFor="email" class='format'>Электронная почта</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
    <div className="mail_descr">
      Можно изменить адрес, указанный при регистрации.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="agree">
    <div className="agree_title">Я согласен</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="consent" name="consent" required />
    <label htmlFor="consent">принимать актуальную информацию на емейл</label>
  </div>

  <div className="btn">
    <button type="submit">Изменить</button>
    <div className="btn_descr">последние изменения 15 мая 2012 в 14:55:17</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Правильно ли я сверстал структуру?

"Правильность" будет сильно зависить от того, что в итоге ты хотел бы получить.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно стилизация ширины лейблов помогла.